# How to retrieve specify data from String Entity

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I have some value for parsing, for example :

```
Student{id=19, groupId=1, firstName='Alex', lastName='Sparrow'}
```

I want to parse this String and get new Arraylist, that will have `1,Alex,Sparrow`.

Only this data.

I want to make general parser even if comes some other object f.e. `Group{id=22, groupName="BKS",groupCity="Moscow"};`

I also will be able to parse it and get List `BKS,groupCity,Moscow`.

Maybe I can use StringBuilder for it but I am not sure.

Comment: Hi, what have you done so far? share some code in order to help you. Moreover what you ask seems a bit wonky. You have key-value pairs (e.g. `groupId=1`) but you want only the values (e.g. `1`) to be present in the List object?. In addition your first example has string values in single quotes e.g. `'Alex'` whereas the second example has double quotes e.g. `"Moscow"`. Are you sure you know exactly what you want to do? Try reconsidering and edit your question adding some code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

In case you only want to get only attribute values. You can consider parse by key-value.

```
Student{id=19, groupId=1, firstName='Alex', lastName='Sparrow'}
```

Get the string in {}

```
id=19, groupId=1, firstName='Alex', lastName='Sparrow'
```

Then split by ",", you will get array of key=value.

Use loop to continue to split key and value by =

```
for(string item: data.split(",")){
    String[] keyValues = item.split("=")
    String key = keyValues[0];
    String value = keyValues[1];
}
```

In case you want to convert to DTO or Pojo, You will have more step to convert key-value to object field.

you can use java reflection to set value for field by name.

https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have string:

```
String string = "Student{id=19, groupId=1, firstName='Alex', lastName='Sparrow'}";
```

Use regular expression to clear string from whitespaces, text before `{`, and `{` and `}` characters itself (it may need adjustments if value or key can contain whitespaces) with:

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\s|.*\\{|\\}","");
```

Create a map, which is perfect for key-value pairs, makes it easy and fast to get value based on key. Additionaly HashMap will also ensure that keys are unique:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Populate map with splitted string data:

```
for (String item : string.split(",")){
        map.put(item.split("=")[0],item.split("=")[1]);
}
```

Now you can get your data with `map.get(String key)`. For example:

```
map.get("groupId");
```

And use all map methods as described in: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html